# Disable .js file for specific media query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I want to disable my .js file when a browser window is less than 1000px but I also want to disable it for specific devices / media queries.

So for example, I want to make sure it doesn't load on iPad.

I have got the 1000px part sorted but I am not sure how to also implement the media query?

```
<script>
$(function() {
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth > 1000){
    skrollr.init({
        forceHeight: false
    });
}});
</script>
```

Comment: It is AFAIK not possible. Use http://mobiledetect.net ( my choice ) if you can use PHP!

Comment: This should help with your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery

Comment: Oh, I got the question the other way around. JS in media-query. Look here: http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect the userAgent, as seen here : [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

In your code :

```
<script>
        $(function() {
             var windowWidth = $(window).width();
          if(windowWidth > 1000 && !(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))){
           skrollr.init({
           forceHeight: false
          });
          }});
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks - This is exactly what I was trying to find!